# Authentication Application layer to reach backed services

Tags: web-services, authentication, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, middleware

I have two web-applications, one running on port 8001 and another running on 8002 and another stand-alone auth-application running on 8090.

I want every request to first pass through auth-application:8090 and then this decides whether it should be processed by web-application:8001 or by web-application:8002.

There could be multiple auth-application which could be decided by putting a Load-balancer on top of those and several web-application cluster and the auth-application decides the web-application cluster to forward the request.

By meaning on several web-application cluster, I mean one cluster is built on Java application and another cluster is composed on Django web-application. I want to decide the cluster based on request-header or request parameters.

What is the best away to achieve this?

I could think of using a script to be called in nginx `proxy_pass` block but am not sure how this could work or even if this would work. There might be some existing implementation for this problem; Might Google / Amazon use this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Usually authentication flow is initiated from the application (how the auth server should know where do you want to go after the successful auth?), so the flow should be:
1. user reaches app
2. app checks if user is authenticated
3. if no, redirects to auth service
4. let's you in (based on the success of the auth)

So the users should know first of all what app do they want (8001 or 8002). If the two apps are the same then it's a loadbalancer you need but the auth flow still has to be initiated from the app.